# Backing up work on a branch using heroku, rails and git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Rails/Heroku/Git newbie - here is my question.  I have an app deployed with Heroku and am using the git repository hosted there as the only remote copy of my local work.  I start making changes locally on a new branch and want to make this branch available on Heroku so that I can continue work on it from another computer.  Heroku ignores branches other than master and I don't want to merge my changes yet (or push them as master).  Is there a way to store/access my new branch via my Heroku git repository, or is it better to have another remote git repository for my work in progress.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could get Heroku to keep some other ref, would you really want to risk them deleting the extra refs without notice after finding that you skirted their “nothing but `master`” policy? You should really consider finding a fully functional [Git-hosting service](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting).

Answer (score 0):

You can push a local branch to the remote git server with:

```
git push origin branch_name
```

That way, you can pull it down again elsewhere with:

```
git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name
```

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html
http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/09/checkout-remote-tracked-branch.html

Answer (score -1):

I would go with a separate git repository as suggested - github.com or similar. Store your code there and deploy to Heroku's master repo - Heroku is a hosting platform afterall not a home for your repos.

*ALTERNATIVELY* Make use of [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) and create your local workspace in a dropbox folder that is synced across multiple computers - I employ this method as well as git - plus you get the advantage that Dropbox is versioned so if you delete/change a file that you haven't committed yet you can get it back.